# Are there any revenue sharing blog websites that pay out in Bitcoin?

Tags: websites

There are plenty of revenue-sharing blog websites [out there](http://www.squidoo.com/income-blogging) (ie they share advertising revenue with the bloggers) but it would make a lot of sense for payments to be made out in Bitcoin, as transaction fees would be very low and the minimum payment amount could be kept small. It would also easily allow participants of any nationality.

Are there any blog hosting sites that share revenue and payout in Bitcoin?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a shopping list question, to which there never can be a definitive answer, and which invites spam.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://anonymousads.com/ on a blog site. They pay in Bitcoin but don't host anything themselves as far as I know

Comment: Site didn't load for me when I tried it just now... (just hung)

Answer (score 1):

StrongCoin Wallet pays affiliates a share of revenue. https://strongcoin.com/en/blog/strongcoin_affiliate_program

Comment: Not a blog site, but it could be used on any blog I suppose... thanks!